# How to always remove inline style for specific element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, styles, inline-styles

How to always remove inline style for specific element?

I use this code to remove my style :

```
jQuery('.myelement').removeAttr('style');
```

but it's not work probably because another js code is adding inline style after me code to remove it. There is no .js file after my file is called.

I know I can edit the .js file from the photo plugin but if I update the plugin, I will loose my changes.

How can I write in jQuery something to tell that this element will **never** have inline style?

Answer (score 0):

To ensure an items style is always empty, even if some other code runs after yours you can use a mutation observer to reset the style whenever the style attribute of the node changes, like this

```js
let element = document.querySelector(".myelement");

let observer = new MutationObserver((m) => {
  if (element.style.length > 0) {
    element.style = {};
  }
});

observer.observe(element, {
  attributes: true,
  attributeFilter: ["style"]
});


// now this wont do anything
element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

```html
<div class="myelement">
  unicorn
</div>
```